# pcap (wireshark) filter by wlan mac address

Tags: c, wireshark, pcap, libpcap

There are (up to) 4 fields in an 802.11 frame that contain mac addresses:

- `source mac`
- `transmitter mac`
- `destination mac`
- `receiver mac`

Is there a pcap capture filter for these values?  Something similar to `ether host ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`, for example.

I've looked at the [PCAP-FILTER Manpage](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) and it is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution, thanks to this answer: [Server Fault - Is there some capture filter (or alternatives) that is especially useful for wireless capture?](https://serverfault.com/questions/359887/is-there-some-capture-filter-or-alternatives-that-is-especially-useful-for-wir).

**Source Address:**
`wlan src XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` or `wlan sa XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`
**Destination Address:**
`wlan dst XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` or `wlan da XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`
**Receiver Address:**
`wlan addr1 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` or `wlan ra XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`
**Transmitter Address:**
`wlan addr2 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` or `wlan ta XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

Support for ra and ta was added to pcap in 2010 per release notes:

> Fri.    August 6, 2010.  guy@alum.mit.edu. Summary for 1.1.2 libpcap
>   release
>
> - Return DLT_ values, not raw LINKTYPE_ values from pcap_datalink() when reading pcap-ng files
> - Add support for "wlan ra" and "wlan ta", to check the RA and TA of WLAN frames that have them
> - Don't crash if "wlan addr{1,2,3,4}" are used without 802.11      headers